# Gram-Schmidt upper triangular basis

Tags: lattice-crypto, lenstra-lenstra-lovasz

I'm trying to understand the Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization process. Below, there is an explanation that a lattice basis can be described by an upper triangular vector.

> It is often convenient to rotate our coordinates to that the Gram-Schmidt vectors are aligned with the standard basis. In these coordinates, our basis $(\pmb{b}_1,\dots,\pmb{b}_n)$ becomes upper triangular, $$
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     \lVert\widetilde{\pmb{b}}_1\rVert & \mu_{1,2}\lVert\widetilde{\pmb{b}}_1\rVert & \mu_{1,3}\lVert\widetilde{\pmb{b}}_1\rVert & \cdots & \mu_{1,n}\lVert\widetilde{\pmb{b}}_1\rVert \\
>     0 & \lVert\widetilde{\pmb{b}}_2\rVert & \mu_{2,3}\lVert\widetilde{\pmb{b}}_2\rVert & \cdots & \mu_{2,n}\lVert\widetilde{\pmb{b}}_2\rVert \\
>     0 & 0 & \lVert\widetilde{\pmb{b}}_3\rVert & \cdots & \mu_{3,n}\lVert\widetilde{\pmb{b}}_3\rVert \\
>     \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
>     0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lVert\widetilde{\pmb{b}}_n\rVert
>     \end{pmatrix}
> $$

I cannot figure out this representation. How does our basis vector become this kind of matrix? And when will we use this representation?

Comment: What is the link? The image of the standard basis under a rotation or reflection (or any orthogonal transformation) is also orthonormal, and every orthonormal basis for $R^n$ arises in this fashion.

Comment: Where the Lattice is defined? that is crucial. The above comment was over $R$. Each base vector ( assuming the columns are base vector) must be orthogonal to others ($\langle x, y \rangle = 0$, i.e. the inner product is zero) to each other. The context is missing! Since if it is integers then the $mu_{i,j}$ must be zero!